# making more space on ubuntu 12.04

Tags: partitioning

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to re-partition?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/120484/how-to-re-partition)

I been running ubuntu 12.04 with a lot of problems blured status texts,no sound, and now running out of space on my 80G hard drive. I think I gave ubuntu too much of my hard drive (74%). I was wondering if it is possible to make more free space on my hard drive by cutting back on ubuntu's partition.

Comment: By Using GParted from the Ubuntu Live CD.

Comment: Try a search here for '[resize partitions](http://askubuntu.com/search?q=resize+partitions)', there are multiple good answers that will walk you through the process. Back up everything important before you do any re-sizing since it doesn't always go perfectly.

Answer (score -1):

I think you had done your partitioning wrong.
Please partition your HDD in this way.....

- /boot  ext2    500 MB
- swap           3000 MB
- /      ext4    12000 MB would be fine.
- /home  ext4    "*Minimum 5000 MB.*"

And after installing you can create new partition with free space.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question really. It's a recommendation for a partitioning scheme and it doesn't explain how to shrink an existing Ubuntu partition.